Derivation of stochastic Bellman equation
Say I have a problem of the form
$$
\max_{\{C_t\}_{t=1}^\infty} E_0\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\beta^tU(C_t;Z_t) \\
s.t. C_t \in \Gamma(X_t) \\ 
X_{t+1}=g(X_t, C_t),
$$
where $C_t$ are my control variables, $X_t$ are my state variables, and $Z_t$ are my exogenous shocks to the system (They are Markov but not necessarily discrete), and where the goal is to find a consumption schedule $\{C_t\}_{t=0}^\infty$ for any possible realisation of the exogenous shocks. As much as I understand, this is a standard goal in economics.
I was then wondering whether the following argument for the derivation of the Bellman equation is correct:
Starting with just the objective function, we can write
$$
\begin{split}
V(X_0) &= \max_{\{C_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}}\left\{U(C_0; Z_0) + \beta E_0E_1\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\beta^{t-1}U(C_t; Z_t)\right\} \\
&=\max_{C_0}\left\{ U(C_0; Z_0) + \beta\max_{\{C_t\}_{t=1}^{\infty}}[E_0E_1\sum_{t=1}^\infty \beta^{t-1}U(C_t; Z_t)]\right\}
\end{split}
$$
Because the consumption schedule must be optimal given any $\{Z_t\}_{t=1}^\infty$, it will also be optimal on average, allowing us to exchange $E_0$ and the max operator (Can I argue for it like this?). This then results in
$$
\begin{split}
V(X_0) &= \max_{C_0}\left\{ U(C_0; Z_0) + \beta E_0\max_{\{C_t\}_{t=1}^{\infty}}[E_1\sum_{t=1}^\infty \beta^{t-1}U(C_t; Z_t)]\right\} \\
&= \max_{C_0}\left\{ U(C_0; Z_0) + \beta E_0 V(X_1)\right\}
\end{split}
$$
I am unsure about the argument for exchanging $E_0$ and the $\max$ operator. Does my argument work or is there another reason why these two are exchanged in the Bellman equation?
